# Polymer and selector inside local DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer-1.0

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-styles/paper-styles.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-fab/paper-fab.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-spinner/paper-spinner.html">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<dom-module id="paperfabtest-element">

<template>
    <paper-spinner id="spinner" active></paper-spinner>
    <BR><paper-fab id="second_button" mini icon="refresh" title="refresh" tabindex="0" class="cyan" onclick="spinner_stop()"></paper-fab>
</template>

<script>
    var el;

    Polymer({
        is: "paperfabtest-element",

        ready: function() {
            el = this.$$("#spinner");
        }
    });

    function spinner_stop() {
        el.active=false;
    }

</script>

</dom-module>
```

Style and some unwanted codes removed.
This local-DOM got a paper-fab and it will stop the spinner when clicked. The above codes work fine.

For some reason i am using the classic way of "onclick" to trigger a function() to stop the spinner, rather than using the "on-click" and event handling inside the Polymer Registration.

Is there a direct way to select this "#spinner" inside the function()?

**Update:**
Finally i find that the code doesn't work when it is inside a jQuery.ajax call
Any idea ?

```
<script>

    Polymer({
        is: "My-element",

        properties: {
            spinner_obj: Object
        },

        updateData: function() {

            this.$$("#spinner").active = true; //this will work
            jQuery.ajax({   
                'async': true,
                'global': false,
                'cache': false, 
                'url': 'Some_URL',
                'dataType': "json",
                'beforeSend': function () {
                },
                'success': function (responseText) {
                    //Do Something
                    this.$$("#spinner").active = true;  //this will promot for error
                    this.$.spinner.active = true;       //this will promot for error
                    spinner_obj.active = false;         //No error but no effect

                }
            });

        },


        ready: function() {
            //Do something
            spinner_obj = this.$$("#spinner");
            this.updateData();
        }

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can and you've already done it in your ready function.

```
var spinnerElement = this.$$("#spinner");
```

From the [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/utility-functions.html):

> *$$(selector)*. Returns the first node in this element’s local DOM that matches *selector*.

**EDIT**: Looks like your function declaration is in correct. Here is how it should be:

```
<dom-module id="paperfabtest-element">
    <template>
        <paper-spinner id="spinner" active></paper-spinner>
        <br>
        <!-- note use of on-click rather than onclick and no brackets on function call -->
        <paper-fab id="second_button" mini icon="refresh" title="refresh" tabindex="0" class="cyan" on-click="spinner_stop"></paper-fab>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "paperfabtest-element",

            ready: function() {
                el = this.$$("#spinner");
            },
            spinner_stop: function () {
                var spinner = this.$$("#spinner"); // grab the spinner element
                spinner.active = false; // stop the spinnner
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Is there any way to select it directly in the spinner_stop() function, but not in the ready() ? I try $$(selector) or jQuery in the spinner_stop function() but both not work there

Comment: `this.$$("#spinner");` will select it. See [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qrr78LNY9d0JjDXXyJve?p=preview) for a basic example. I have a `div` with an id (that represents your spinner) and a button with an `on-click` event. When the button is clicked, I select the `div` with the id using `var spinner = this.$$("#spinner");` You can then stop the spinner using `spinner.active = false;`

Comment: Thank you. I try this method in the simplified codes and it works. So strange that it still failed when it is implemented in the production codes. Firebug prompt for "ReferenceError: spinner is not defined" and i have to use the old method. I will keep debug :(

Comment: Why do you keep using `$$` when you've already given an `id` to `<paper-spinner>`? You can just reference with `this.$.spinner`, no?

Comment: Yes, it's just personal preference from myself.

Comment: Update: The problem occurred inside the ajax(), Anything wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

this is because inside the ajax call you have a new closure, you need to bind your success function to "this".

```
updateData: function() {

        this.$$("#spinner").active = true; //this will work
        jQuery.ajax({   
            'async': true,
            'global': false,
            'cache': false, 
            'url': 'Some_URL',
            'dataType': "json",
            'beforeSend': function () {
            },
            'success': function (responseText) {
                //Do Something
                this.$.spinner.active = false; //use self here
            }.bind(this)
        });

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Locating the exact the node hidden deep inside the shadow from outer scopes might be complex, potentially inconsistent and is an anti-pattern. Perhaps you can fire a `stop-spinner` event and pass out the target node inside the `event.detail` object instead.

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-styles/paper-styles.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-fab/paper-fab.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-spinner/paper-spinner.html">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<dom-module id="paperfabtest-element">

<template>
    <paper-spinner id="spinner" active></paper-spinner>
    <BR>
    <paper-fab id="second_button" mini icon="refresh" title="refresh" tabindex="0" class="cyan" 
               on-tap="fireStopSpinner">
    </paper-fab>
</template>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "paperfabtest-element",
        fireStopSpinner: function () {
          this.fire("stop-spinner", { targetEl: this.$.spinner });
        }
    });

    // outside of Polymer, you can use jQuery to listen for event
    $("paperfabtest-element").on("stop-spinner", function (e) {
      e.detail.targetEl.active = false;
    });

</script>
```

Comment: If the parent element is a Polymer element, you should use Polymer's listeners to catch the event. As both the button and the spinner are in the same element, you might as well just stop the spinner in this element. Then if required, you can fire and event to a parent to notify that the spinner has been stopped.

Comment: Well, I'm just answering based on what OP says. He wants jQuery, and he does not want to use Polymer's `on-*` listeners. My solution gives him exactly that. Discussion on exactly what he's trying to do, or if what he's doing is an anti-pattern is beyond the scope of the question.